# How do I turn a number into a date?

Tags: python, date

I have a dataset with the dates given in numbers from 1995 to 2016. 
1/1/1995 is equal to 1, 2/1/1995 is 2 and 31/12/2016 is 8036, so every day is one number.

How do I turn my time array [1,2,3,...,8034,8035,8036] into dates of dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: that's ugly but take a look at the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Can't you just make a datetime object or something similar with the value of 1/1/1995 and then add i days to that object where i is the number in your time array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `datetime.fromordinal(x)` method. This creates a date from the number x, signifying the number of days since 0001-01-01.

If you want to start with `x==1` being 1995-01-01, you can do

```
d = datetime.date(1,1,1) # actual date does not matter
print d.fromordinal( datetime.date(1994,12,31).toordinal() + x)
```

where `x` is the number of days since the last day of 1994.

Answer (score 1):

Use the epoch conversion which is also supported by the [python time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html). The unix epoch time starts on 01/01/1970 and is counted in seconds. If you add 788932800 seconds to reach 01/01/1995, you can then add 86400 (seconds per day) and can use standard techniques to calculated the "seconds from epoch" back to a correct date.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
entryid = 5
epochdate = 788932800 + entryid * 86400
print time.strftime("%d/%m/%y", time.gmtime(epochdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help for first 100 days? You can change the no though.

```
import time
epochOne = 788918400 #epoch for 1995-01-01 00:00:00
oneDay = 86400 #epoch for 86400
noOfDays = 8036 

for each in range(noOfDays):
  epochEach = epochOne + (each * oneDay)
  print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(epochEach)))
```